# ngClass not updating in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using a condition in ngClass to set a button to be disabled until _selectedItem is non-null. After _selectedItem is fulfilled to an item, the class doesn't change. What do I need to do to get ngClass to update?

```
 [ngClass]="(_selectedItem == null) ? 'disabled' : ''"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
[class.disabled] = "_selectedItem == null"
```

Or

```
<div [ngClass]="{ disabled: _selectedItem == null }"></div>
```

Comment: Both of your solutions work... And so did mine. I was just using the wrong variable. :,(